# Python - split list in to sublists based on another list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

I have two lists: `l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9]` 
and `l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]`. I want to split `l1` in to sublists that are defined as the elements between two indexes of `l2`. So for example `l1` would be equal to `[[0,0.002, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.9], [1.3], [1.9]]`.

Here is my solution:

```
l3 = []
b=0
for i in l2:
    temp = []
    for p in l1:
        if b <= p < i:
        temp.append(p)
    l3.append(temp)
    b+=0.5
```

This solution is a huge bottleneck in my code. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: So these are buckets. It's a histogram!

Comment: @PeterWood or a hash map! Or an interval tree! So many possibilities!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lists are sorted, so there is no need to do a double loop here.

The following generates the sublists based on the two lists as inputs:

```
def partition(values, indices):
    idx = 0
    for index in indices:
        sublist = []
        while idx < len(values) and values[idx] < index:
            sublist.append(values[idx])
            idx += 1
        if sublist:
            yield sublist
```

You can then iterate over `partition(l1, l2)` to get individual sublists, or call `list()` to produce the whole list-of-lists in one go:

```
>>> l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9] 
>>> l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
>>> list(partition(l1, l2))
[[0, 0.002, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.9], [1.3], [1.9]]
```

Comment: wouldn't this be `O(n*m)`  like op's solution? would there be huge performance gain?

Comment: @taesu: the OPs is O(N*M).

Comment: ahhh, you're right. thanks for that, and also thanks for your participation at SO.

Comment: @taesu, `index` goes through whole list, giving O(n). Now, while iterating over `indices`, `idx` is not decreasing and each iteration of the `while` loop increments `idx` by 1. This gives a maximum of `len (values)` iterations, bumping complexity to `O (n + m)`. In short, both lists are traversed once.

Answer (score 3):

As a fast way you can use `numpy` pretty most efficient way for huge lists :

```
>>> np.split(l1,np.searchsorted(l1,l2))
[array([ 0.   ,  0.002,  0.3  ]), array([ 0.5,  0.6,  0.9]), array([ 1.3]), array([ 1.9]), array([], dtype=float64)]
```

---

[`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) will find the indices of `l2` items within `l1` while `l1` remains sorted (with its default sort) and [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) will split your list based on a list of indices.

A benchmark with accepted answer on a list 1000 time bigger :

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""

def partition(values, indices):
    idx = 0
    for index in indices:
        sublist = []
        while idx < len(values) and values[idx] < index:
            sublist.append(values[idx])
            idx += 1
        if sublist:
            yield sublist

l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9]*1000
l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
list(partition(l1, l2))

"""

s2="""
l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9]*1000
l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
np.split(l1,np.searchsorted(l1,l2))
   """

print '1st: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=10000)
print '2nd : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=10000,setup="import numpy as np")
```

Result :

```
1st:  17.5872459412
2nd :  10.3306460381
```

Comment: You should really move the creating of `l1` and `l2` *out* of the timeit tests (as well as defining the `partition()` function).

Comment: I get 1.43 vs 1.1 for 1000 repetitions. Not bad for a pure-python implementation.

Comment: Ah, there is a problem. You cannot just multiply `l1` by 1000, because my solution *requires `l1` to be sorted*. Not that it helps my case if you do sort the list properly as that makes my solution slightly slower as more results are produced.

Comment: Answered my own question,  my solution using pure python  is faster

Comment: @MartijnPieters With moving `l1` and `l2` out of the timeit test it doesn't make much difference again numpy performs significantly better on large data.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598677/why-list-comprehension-is-much-faster-than-numpy-for-multiplying-arrays

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep as well your answer is elegant but still you need to timeit with large list to find out the power of Numpy ;-)

Comment: @Kasramvd, I timed it with the same size list as your tests ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I meant very huge!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 10000000000000000 time larger! :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_l(a,b):
    it = iter(b)
    start, sub = next(it), []
    for ele in a:
        if ele >= start:
            yield sub
            sub, start = [], next(it)
        sub.append(ele)
    yield sub

print(list(split_l(l1,l2)))
[[0, 0.002, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.9], [1.3], [1.9]]
```

using kasras input this beats both the accepted answer and the numpy solution:

```
In [14]: l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9]*1000

In [15]: l1.sort()

In [16]: l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]

In [17]: timeit list(partition(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop

In [18]: timeit list(split_l(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 703 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit np.split(l1,np.searchsorted(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 802 µs per loop

In [20]: list(split_l(l1,l2))  == list(partition(l1,l2))
Out[20]: True
```

Creating a local reference to append knocks even more off:

```
def split_l(a, b):
    it = iter(b)
    start, sub = next(it), []
    append = sub.append
    for ele in a:
        if start <= ele:
            yield sub
            start, sub = next(it), []
            append = sub.append
        append(ele)
    yield sub
```

Runs in just over the time of the numpy solution:

```
In [47]: l1.sort()

In [48]: timeit list(split_l(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop

In [49]: timeit list(partition(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop

In [50]: timeit np.split(l1,np.searchsorted(l1,l2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 812 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [0, 0.002, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3, 1.9]

l2 = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]


  def partition(values, indices):

    temp = []
    p_list = []


    for j in range(len(indices)):
        for i in range(len(values)):
            if indices[j] > values[i]:
                temp.append(values[i])

        p_list.append(temp)

        # added to the partition values are truncated from the list
        values = values[len(temp):]

        temp = []

    print(p_list)
```

partition(l1, l2)

[[0, 0.002, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.9], [1.3], [1.9]]

Comment: This is just as bad as the OP's solution; you have a O(N*M) quadratic algorithm here.