# numpy, get maximum of subsets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, vectorization

I have an array of values, said `v`, (e.g. `v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`) and an array of indexes, say `g` (e.g.            `g=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]`).

I know, for instance, how to take the first element of each group, in a very numpythonic way, doing:

```
import numpy as np
v=np.array([1,2,3,4,74,73,72,71,9,10])
g=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2])
mask=np.concatenate(([True],np.diff(g)!=0))
v[mask]
```

returns:

```
array([1, 74, 9])
```

Is there any `numpy`thonic way (avoiding explicit loops) to get the maximum of each subset?

---

### Tests:

Since I received two good answers, one with the python `map` and one with a `numpy` routine, and I was searching the most performing, here some timing tests:

```
import numpy as np
import time
N=10000000
v=np.arange(N)
Nelemes_per_group=10
Ngroups=N/Nelemes_per_group
s=np.arange(Ngroups)
g=np.repeat(s,Nelemes_per_group)

start1=time.time()
r=np.maximum.reduceat(v, np.unique(g, return_index=True)[1])
end1=time.time()
print('END first method, T=',(end1-start1),'s')

start3=time.time()
np.array(list(map(np.max,np.split(v,np.where(np.diff(g)!=0)[0]+1))))
end3=time.time()
print('END second method,  (map returns an iterable) T=',(end3-start3),'s')
```

As a result I get:

```
END first method, T= 1.6057236194610596 s
END second method,  (map returns an iterable) T= 8.346540689468384 s
```

Interestingly, most of the slowdown of the `map` method is due to the `list()` call. If I do not try to reconvert my `map` result to a `list` ( but I have to, because `python3.x` returns an iterator:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `np.maximum.reduceat`:

```
>>> _, idx = np.unique(g, return_index=True)
>>> np.maximum.reduceat(v, idx)
array([ 4, 74, 10])
```

More about the workings of the ufunc `reduceat` method can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).

---

*Remark about performance*

`np.maximum.reduceat` is very fast. Generating the indices `idx` is what takes most of the time here.

While `_, idx = np.unique(g, return_index=True)` is an elegant way to get the indices, it is not particularly quick.

The reason is that `np.unique` needs to sort the array first, which is O(n log n) in complexity. For large arrays, this is much more expensive than using several O(n) operations to generate `idx`.

Therefore, for large arrays it is much faster to use the following instead:

```
idx = np.concatenate([[0], 1+np.diff(g).nonzero()[0]])
np.maximum.reduceat(v, idx)
```

Comment: amazing! everytime I discover some new strange `numpy` function ;D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Divakar - that's much nicer.

Comment: `reduceat` combined with a ranking (here not necessary because `g` is already in a nice form) is I think the "approved" way to get a groupby in pure numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your mask like following and use `map` function :

```
>>> mask=np.diff(g)!=0
>>> map(np.max,np.split(v,np.where(mask)[0]+1))
[4, 74, 10]
```

If you don't want to get a generator with `map` you can use a list comprehension to achieve same result in list, and note that the iteration of list comprehension has performed at C language speed inside the interpreter, like built-in functions.

```
[np.max(arr) for arr in np.split(v,np.where(mask)[0]+1)]
```

But I think the numpythonic solution still is better to use.

Comment: nice one, I will probably use it as long as I do not have any `numpy`tonic solution. In fact, this will have a (non C based) loop over the subset, which in my real case, is quite large.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin `map()` is a built in function in python and its iterations performed at C language speed inside the interpreter.

Comment: interesting, please see my update on the anwer where I compared the codes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really didn't know those iterations where made at a C level, and in fact they are ways faster than I thougt, and difference with numpy comes only with objects of sizes >10000000 elements

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Your welcome. Yes, numpy showe it's power against huge data sets ;-) Read this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598677/why-list-comprehension-is-much-faster-than-numpy-for-multiplying-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Here's one convoluted vectorized approach using [`masking`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)  that puts each group into rows of a regular 2D array and then finds maximum along each row -

```
# Mask of valid numbers from each group to be put in a regular 2D array
counts = np.bincount(g)
mask = np.arange(counts.max()) < counts[:,None]

# Group each group into rows of a 2D array and find max along ech row
grouped_2Darray = np.empty(mask.shape)
grouped_2Darray.fill(np.nan)
grouped_2Darray[mask] = v
out = np.nanmax(grouped_2Darray,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [52]: g
Out[52]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

In [53]: v
Out[53]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 74, 73, 72, 71,  9, 10])

In [54]: grouped_2Darray # Notice how elements from v are stacked
Out[54]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [ 74.,  73.,  72.,  71.],
       [  9.,  10.,  nan,  nan]])

In [55]: np.nanmax(grouped_2Darray,1)
Out[55]: array([  4.,  74.,  10.])
```